# Membership not generated by membership contribution 4.6.18

Tags: contributions, contribution-page

We are upgrading our database from 4.4.7 to 4.6.18.

On testing, there is an issue related to pending membership payments, generated by the Civi contribution page, not generating a membership on the membership tab when the membership contribution is marked as completed.

I've tested as a new member opting to pay later on our  database, then opened the contact record as a member of staff would on receiving funds to mark this contribution as complete. On our live CiviCRM 4.4.7. database, this results in the membership appearing as new, but on CiviCRM 4.6.18. nothing appears on the membership tab.

Is this a bug or is this how 4.6.18 works?

Comment: please test the same against http://d46.demo.civicrm.org - I guess you need to check your installation

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a price set? If so, look at the price sets and make sure that each for membership has a Membership Type chosen in the first field drop-down menu. The notation there states:
"***If a membership type is selected, a membership will be created*** or renewed when users select this option. Leave this blank if you are using this for non-membership options (e.g. magazine subscription)."

I found that some of mine were empty thus no membership records were created; only the contributions were. This is a bit arcane and not obvious if not researched.

Here are some pics:

https://imagebin.ca/36uQhc0anGfS/civicrm-PriceSets.jpg

https://imagebin.ca/36uR45kYYMny/civicrm-PriceSets-PriceFields.jpg

https://imagebin.ca/36uRKx3WsIvy/civicrm-PriceSets-PriceOption.jpg

Also, I am finding that if you enter the membership using New Contribution it will not record it in the Membership Manager. You have to enter it as New Membership and then the Membership Dues will be recorded as a contribution. This is a little clunky but the workflow is understandable.

Comment: Thanks Bruce that is really useful, the issue seemed to resolve but I will use this as a reference if it reoccurs, I also found the same regarding adding a contribution. Thanks again!